# How do i fix my docker backend to work from port 80

Tags: docker

I have a larvel container, a mysql container, a mongodb container and a "test" container.

the container of domainname.test states it is running on port 80, but localhost doesn't show anything running and there is nothing shown thorough postman.

here is the information on inspecting the domainname.test in docker:

```
    PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/artisan:18

Stack trace:

#0 {main}

  thrown in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/artisan:18

Stack trace:

#0 {main}

  thrown in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/artisan:18

Stack trace:

#0 {main}

  thrown in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/artisan:18

Stack trace:

#0 {main}

  thrown in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

2022-04-20 11:35:15,237 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded

2022-04-20 11:35:15,238 INFO supervisord started with pid 9

2022-04-20 11:35:16,239 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 10

2022-04-20 11:35:16,338 INFO exited: php (exit status 255; not expected)

2022-04-20 11:35:17,340 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 11

2022-04-20 11:35:17,376 INFO exited: php (exit status 255; not expected)

2022-04-20 11:35:19,379 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 12

2022-04-20 11:35:19,415 INFO exited: php (exit status 255; not expected)

2022-04-20 11:35:22,420 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 13

2022-04-20 11:35:22,458 INFO exited: php (exit status 255; not expected)

2022-04-20 11:35:23,459 INFO gave up: php entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly

2022-04-20 12:57:32,293 INFO Set uid to user 0 succeeded

2022-04-20 12:57:32,296 INFO supervisord started with pid 8

2022-04-20 12:57:33,298 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 9

2022-04-20 12:57:33,352 INFO exited: php (exit status 255; not expected)

2022-04-20 12:57:34,355 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 10

2022-04-20 12:57:34,399 INFO exited: php (exit status 255; not expected)

2022-04-20 12:57:36,403 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 11

2022-04-20 12:57:36,436 INFO exited: php (exit status 255; not expected)

2022-04-20 12:57:39,442 INFO spawned: 'php' with pid 12

2022-04-20 12:57:39,476 INFO exited: php (exit status 255; not expected)

2022-04-20 12:57:40,478 INFO gave up: php entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly

PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/artisan:18

Stack trace:

#0 {main}

  thrown in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/artisan:18

Stack trace:

#0 {main}

  thrown in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/artisan:18

Stack trace:

#0 {main}

  thrown in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/artisan:18

Stack trace:

#0 {main}

  thrown in /var/www/html/artisan on line 18
```

There is also a message that appears root container:

```
sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /mnt/c/Users/Alex

no configuration file provided: not found
```

any clue what to look into would be hugely appreciated.

I need to get this working as a local backend for working on the website.

.dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.10

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=16

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN php artisan cache:clear

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev \
       php8.1-pgsql php8.1-mongodb php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd \
       php8.1-curl \
       php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring \
       php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap \
       php8.1-intl php8.1-readline \
       php8.1-ldap \
       php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole \
       php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.1

RUN groupadd --force -g 1000 sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g 1000 -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    domainname.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '1000'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        container_name: "domainname.test"
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '1000'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        container_name: "mysql"
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    pma:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: "uth_pma"
      links:
        - mysql:mysql
      ports:
        - '${PMA_PORT:-8080}:80'
      environment:
        MYSQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USERNAME}"
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
      networks:
        - sail
    mongo:
      image: 'mongo:latest'
      container_name: 'mongodb_container'
      restart: always
      environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: '${MONGO_DB_USERNAME}'
        MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}'
        MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: '${MONGO_DB_DATABASE}'
      ports:
        - '${FORWARD_MONGO_DB_PORT:-27017}:27017'
      volumes:
        - 'sail-mongo:/data/db'
      networks:
        - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-mongo:
      driver: local
```

output of docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                    PORTS                                     NAMES
fe7b09105778   sail-8.1/app             "start-container"        2 hours ago   Up 53 minutes             0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 8000/tcp              domainname.test
449d960217fc   phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin    "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 hours ago   Up 53 minutes             0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                      uth_pma
5befecec008c   mongo:latest             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 53 minutes             0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp                  mongodb_container
1a8400e77220   mysql/mysql-server:8.0   "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   2 hours ago   Up 53 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060-33061/tcp   mysql
```

docker network details::

```
NETWORK ID     NAME         DRIVER    SCOPE
525b4eb518ef   bridge       bridge    local
569d0af82146   host         host      local
3659352e5f1b   lback_sail   bridge    local
d454e04dd56e   none         null      local

$ docker network inspect -v NETWORK lback_sail
[
    {
        "Name": "lback_sail",
        "Id": "hidden id",
        "Created": "2022-04-20T11:22:22.987596082Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "hidden number": {
                "Name": "mysql",
                "EndpointID": "hidden number",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "hidden number": {
                "Name": "uth_pma",
                "EndpointID": "hidden id",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "hidden id": {
                "Name": "mongodb_container",
                "EndpointID": "hidden id",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "hidden id": {
                "Name": "domainname.test",
                "EndpointID": "hidden id",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "sail",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "lback",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.4.1"
        }
    }
]
Error: No such network: NETWORK
```

Comment: only command used was :
sudo docker compose build --no-cache && docker compose up in the root

Comment: ok, it looks like domainname.test must be listening to port 80 on the Host. (Unless you have another number in APP_PORT variable). 
Can you post the output of "docker ps -a" ? And maybe also of "docker network inspect" ?

Comment: first setup, it is already working on someones mac, this is through wsl-2

Comment: "0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 8000/tcp              domainname.test"  This says it all: Your Host has something listening on port 80. No doubt about it. The problem is somewhere else. Sorry, I don't know Laravel but you need to look in there I guess.

Comment: thankyou :) ill look thoruhg and fiddle. Could this be the php here "        - '${PMA_PORT:-8080}:80'" ?

Comment: Nope, that line says that internal port 80 is mapped to 8080 on the Host. It says that there something listening to port 8080 on the Host.

Comment: the only thing i can find otherwise is the "expose 8000" maybe should be "expose 80" ?

Comment: do you mean by host, the local computer im using to run docker? As i cant seem to see anything running currently on 80,